# FullCalendar eventClick and dayClick not working with arguments

Tags: symfony, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar, below is my settings:

```
$(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left:   '',
            center: '',
            right:  ''
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        lazyFetching: true,
        timeFormat: {
            // for agendaWeek and agendaDay
            agenda: 'h:mmt',    // 5:00 - 6:30

            // for all other views
            '': 'h:mmt'         // 7p
        },
        isRTL: true,
        lang: 'fa',
        editable: true,
        disableResizing: true,
        dayNamesShort: ['یک‌شنبه', 'دوشنبه', 'سه‌شنبه', 'چهارشنبه', 'پنج‌شنبه', 'جمعه', 'شنبه'],
        firstDay: 6,
        events: [
            {
                title  : 'event1',
                start  : '2016-01-24'
            },
            {
                title  : 'event2',
                start  : '2016-01-24',
                end    : '2016-01-25'
            },
            {
                title  : 'event3',
                start  : '2016-01-22',
                allDay : true // will make the time show
            }
        ],
        eventClick: function() {
            alert('win');
        }
    });
});
```

when clicking on a event, no action triggers. I've looked everywhere and couldn't find any answers.
currently, i'm integrating FC with symfony2.
also, here are my assets:

```
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {'callback': 'fos.Router.setData'}) }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/moment.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/adesignscalendar/js/fullcalendar/jquery.fullcalendar.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/lang-all.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: I put together a jsfiddle with your init params here (http://jsfiddle.net/b3qqy9Lm/). The eventClick is working, so i'm thinking it is either the integration with symphony or the fullCalendar version. The fiddle is 2.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
selectable: true,
eventClick: function( event, jsEvent, view ) { 
// your code
}
```